# Can someone explain what purpose passing by pointer and passing by reference have in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I just can't understand why should I use them instead of variables.

For example, can someone explains why this doesn't work:

```
void swap(int x, int y) {
  int z = x;
  x = y;
  y = z;
}

int main() {
  int x, y;
  x = 5, y = 4;
  swap(x, y);
  cout << x << " " << y;
}
```

But this does:

```
void swap(int *x, int *y) {
  int z = *x;
  *x = *y;
  *y = z;
}

int main() {
  int x, y;
  x = 5, y = 4;
  swap(&x, &y);
  cout << x << " " << y;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example you gave you are passing the parameters by value, this creates a copy of the variables in memory and the function operates on the copy. This means that the original value of x and y do not get modified, only their copies do. When the function ends the copies are destroyed and the original values remain untouched.

In the second example you pass in a pointer, a pointer just "points" to the memory where your variable x and y are stored. When you de-reference (the * operator) a pointer you can use the variable as you would any other, meaning that doing:

```
*x = *y;
```

You are actually setting the variable at memory address x to the value of the variable at memory address y. Unlike the first code snippet this changes the value of the variable globally.

In short, passing by value creates a duplicate of x for you function to use. After the function finishes x is destroyed and the original x variable remains untouched. Passing by pointer or reference means you pass in where x is stored, and then access the x variable. When the function ends x remains modified.

**Why do they exist?**
Simply put it is useful for large objects to pass the pointer to them instead, as creating duplicates of classes or structures which have large memory footprints is really slow.

**When should you pass by value**
When you simply want a copy of the data but not to modify the original, usually because modifying the original is unnecessary or harmful to the application.

**When should you pass by reference**
When you want to modify the original value of the variable within a function.

**When should I use a pointer?**
When you want to modify the variable in memory or assign an entirely new variable to that memory address.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer this in two parts.

First, why the two pairs of code behaves differently. This is simple enough. When you call a function and either pass by reference or use a pointer, the function is looking at the memory locations of the variables and then modifying the contents of those memory locations. So when you make a change to the variables (or swap variables), that change will be visible outside of the function call.

In the first set of code, the int values that you are passing into the function are actually being copied to new temporary variables only defined inside the function. So the function is working with the same numbers, but when it modifies them the modifications are only to those copied variables, not the originals.

So, why should you pass by reference. The main reason I usually pass by reference in my code is because it is faster. If you are passing a large object into a function you don't want to have to copy all that data over. (Granted, this speed may be negligible for the purposes of most code, but it doesn't hurt to save time.) The other reason you would care, as can be seen here is when you want to change the object and have those changes reflected outside the function.

On the other hand, if you want to make changes to the object but not have it affect the original, you would not want to pass by reference. An example of this might be if you have a function that does an argsort on a vector, and the implementation of the argsort also sorted the vector. You wouldn't want to actually modify the vector, which it would if you passed by reference. But if you pass a vector into a function normally it will just copy the vector into a new temporary variable and sort that one, leaving the initial vector untouched.

Also, be warned that some languages such as python (and I think Java) always pass by reference.

Comment: `Also, be warned that some languages such as python (and I think Java) always pass by reference.` That is not true, at least not for how _"passed-by-reference"_ is defined in c++. If you have a `def get_string(the_string): the_string = 'something'` and you do `get_string(val)`, then `val` would not hold `something`. In Python, Java, JavaScript,  it is _"pass-by-value"_, but the value that is passed is the reference (except for immutable primitives). So from the c++ perspective,  Python, Java, JS, ... do a _"pass-by-reference-copy"_ and  _"pass-by-value-copy"_.